# i can't uploading image to the server using ios Device PHP

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to upload an image from iPhone iOS using PHP/javascript, to the destination folder but when I checked the folder was empty

It only works fine with my desktop but not with my iPhone, I don't know what the problem is, any help I would appreciate

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE | E_NOTICE);
@ini_set('html_errors','0');
@ini_set('display_errors','0');
@ini_set('display_startup_errors','0');
@ini_set('log_errors','0');

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $uploadDir = '../myimg/'; // Create a folder named 'uploads' in the same directory as this PHP file.

    if (!file_exists($uploadDir)) {
        mkdir($uploadDir, 0777, true);
    }

    $uploadedFile = $uploadDir . basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $uploadedFile)) {
        echo 'Image uploaded successfully: ' . $uploadedFile;
    } else {
        echo 'Error uploading image.';
    }
}

?>
```

```js
function uploadImage() {
  var formData = new FormData();
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('imageInput');

  if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
    formData.append('image', fileInput.files[0]);

    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('POST', '../common/upload.php', true);

    xhr.onload = function() {
      if (xhr.status === 200) {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Error uploading image.';
      }
    };

    xhr.send(formData);
  } else {
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = 'Please select an image.';
  }
}
```

Comment: You've instructed PHP to not give you any errors, so I'd turn that back on to start. Also, since you are capturing errors, `xhr.status` will always be 200. During development, leave all the errors and exceptions on, otherwise debugging is a giant pain.

Comment: @Chris Haas i removed the debugging functions and tested again on iphone it given me no errors logs the script pass normally but still there no image uploaded on the server

Comment: My recommendation would be to skip AJAX for now, just make a normal boring form with POST. Get that working on your device. If it doesn't inspect `$_FILES`